# laravel LengthAwarePaginator class not working

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

i'm trying to create a pagination manually in laravel but its returning all the items in my model instead of the 'perPage' value that i set , below is my code :

```
$a = mazee\ad::all();
  $p = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($a ,count($a),3, 1);

   dd($p) ;
```

Also all the links : '?page=2' , '?page=3' , '?page=4' are outputing the same result[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see the usage example of `\Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` in the class `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`:

```
/**
     * Paginate the given query into a simple paginator.
     *
     * @param  int  $perPage
     * @param  array  $columns
     * @param  string  $pageName
     * @param  int|null  $page
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
     */
    public function paginate($perPage = 15, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null)
    {
        $page = $page ?: Paginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

        $total = $this->getCountForPagination($columns);

        $results = $total ? $this->forPage($page, $perPage)->get($columns) : [];

        return new LengthAwarePaginator($results, $total, $perPage, $page, [
            'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
            'pageName' => $pageName,
        ]);
    }
```

The first parameter passed to LengthAwarePaginator ($results), shouldn't be all rows from your model. Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 3):

finally I solved it like so :

```
    class maincontroller extends Controller
{
        public function getprofile(){
          $a = mazee\ad::all()->toarray();

          $this->paginate($a , 5)->items();

         }



            public function paginate($items , $perpage ){
             $total = count($items);
            $currentpage = \Request::get('page', 1);
            $offset = ($currentpage * $perpage) - $perpage ;
            $itemstoshow = array_slice($items , $offset , $perpage);
            $p = new LengthAwarePaginator($itemstoshow ,$total ,$perpage);
             $p->setPath('http://localhost/agroexpresslink.com/profile');
            return $p;
      }
}
```